# Submitting a HTML form in and onload function

Tags: javascript, html

I want send a form as soon as the page is loaded. All variables in the form are written dynamically and there is no button for submitting.

Does following JS script work in all browsers ?

```
<script type='text/javascript'> window.onload = function(){ window.document.forms[0].submit(); }; </script>
```

I doubt `window.onload` will work in all without any problems.

Thanks in advance...

Comment: I wonder what use case requires this?

Comment: not when the browser has javascript disabled

Comment: @Vincent: A redirect to a POST.

Comment: @Vincent, yes @SLaks is right. it is for a payment gateway

Answer (score 14, accepted):

If you're worried about compatibility in all browsers, how about using jQuery's ready function?

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function() {
    window.document.forms[0].submit();
  });
</script>
```

Comment: this probably more logical for compatibility

Answer (score 6):

Whilst I would agree that [Ken's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6209116/31532) is perfectly acceptable, I don't believe it is correct to include a full-fat JS library just for its `.ready()` functionality.

For what it's worth, I'd recommend [docReady](https://github.com/jfriend00/docReady). The size of docReady is 322 bytes gzipped (548 bytes uncompressed).

```
docReady(function() {
  window.document.forms[0].submit();
});
```

I love jQuery, and I'd even say that there's not much of a perf impact in Ken's answer because it's likely that, if you're using the Google CDN, you've probably already downloaded it during your time on that site or others. But still, it's an unnecessary overhead on what should be a simple page IMO.

Answer (score 3):

Don't use the window.onload (I mean, you can, but is easier/ more logical to do it differently). What you should do is print the form in a hidden div tag, assign an id to the submit button and then use javascript to 'click' it. Here is an example:

```
<div style="display: hidden;">
    <form action="page/site" method="get/post">
        <input type="hidden" name="name" value="value" />
        <input type="submit" id="formButton" />
    </form>
    <script language="javascript">
        document.getElementById("formButton").click();
    </script>
</div>
```

I hope that helps.

Comment: Uh... why? Where is the benefit of this approach compared to window.onload?

Comment: Well, it groups it together, mainly. If it's a single and simple page with only the form that needs to be executed right way in the code, it's not really an issue, but whenever I have these types of situations, I have them as part of a larger (dynamic) script. Additionally, the onload runs when the DOM has fully loaded. This code will be executed when the browser reads it.

Comment: But you still don't require the submit button or "simulate" a click on this submit button. Calling document.getElementBy('myHiddenForm').submit(); should do the trick just as good, or?

Comment: ...yes. I am not sure why I have it this way (I just copy/ pasted this code from one of my libraries). I think I had a reason for it back when I wrote it. Or maybe I just wasn't wiser at the time x)